# Erro em relacionamento ManyToMany no Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou com um problema com `@manyToMany`. Tá dando o erro:

> org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Segue meu modelo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sar_evento", schema = "sar")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "sar.evento_sequence", schema = "sar")
public class Evento implements Serializable, BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_evento", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String nome;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "data_inicio")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataInicio;

    @Column(name = "data_fim")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataFim;

    @Column(name = "dia_todo")
    private boolean diaTodo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_sala", referencedColumnName = "id_sala")
    private Sala sala;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @OrderBy("nome asc")
    @JoinTable(name = "sar_evento_recurso", schema = "sar",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_evento")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_recurso")})
    private List<Recurso> recursos = new ArrayList<Recurso>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Usuario usuario;
```

alguem já passou por esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro refere-se a casos onde uma *query* realizada no JPA ou Hibernate utiliza o *fetch join* em mais de um relacionamento.

Os *joins* "normais", lazy e eager, trazem as listas relacionadas em comandos `SELECT` subsequentes ao `SELECT` principal, ou seja, ele recupera primeiro a entidade solicitada, depois os dados dos seus relacionamentos.

Isso significa que, em termos de desempenho, o modo *lazy* e o modo *eager* são equivalentes. A diferença é que o *lazy* espera um método *getter* ser invocado para executar as demais queries, enquanto no modo *eager* elas são executadas logo após a principal.

Já o *fetch join* força um *join* nativo no banco de dados, já recuperando tanto a entidade principal quanto as entidades relacionadas. Geralmente isso é usado para fins de otimização.

Entretanto, o Hibernate somente suporta realizar o *fetch join* em uma tabela relacionada. Se tentar fazer com mais de uma, o erro indicado vai ocorrer.

O motivo é bem simples quando você pensa sobre como seria o resultado da *query* com vários joins.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que você tenta recuperar uma lista da entidade `Evento` e faz o *fetch join* com `Recurso`. Se há `N` eventos e `M` recursos para cada evento a consulta retornará `N x M` resultados, nos quais os dados de `Evento` serão repetidos para cada registro do respectivo `Recurso`.

Agora, se tentarmos adicionar mais algum relacionamento, por exemplo `Sala`, os seus valores também serão repetidos `N x M x K` vezes.

Além do desempenho da consulta começar a ficar péssimo, outro problema emerge: é muito complicado processar o resultada da consulta e identificar quais valores repetem e quais devem criar outra entidade na lista.

A solução é recuperar esses relacionamentos em queries separadas e não tentar fazer tudo de uma só vez.

Comment: Somente complementando, alterando de List para Set deve resolver o problema:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags

Comment: Olá eu mudei meu relacionamento para: `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @OrderBy("nome asc") @JoinTable(name = "sar_evento_recurso", schema = "sar", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_evento")}, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_recurso")}) private List<Recurso> recursos = new ArrayList<Recurso>();`. Agora estou tendo problema com sessão: `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed`.

Comment: @JosuéEduardo Ao que parece, mudar para `Set` realmente evita o problema, porém é importante ressaltar que `Set` e `List` não são estruturas equivalentes. No caso desta questão, há um `@OrderBy` no relacionamento. Com o `Set`, não há garantia que a ordem será respeitada.

Comment: @paulohddias Tente resolver voltando para `FetchType.EAGER` e adicionando a anotação `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)`. Isso fará com que a lista seja recuperada em um `SELECT` posterior, evitando problemas com *joins*.

Comment: mudei para `:@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "sar_evento_recurso", schema = "sar",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_evento")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_recurso")})
    private Set<Recurso> recursos = new HashSet<Recurso>();`. Mas continuo tendo erro de sessão quando tento alterar ou deletar, para inserir esta tudo ok.

Comment: @paulohddias Quanto ao erro de `LazyInitializationException`, tem certeza que não é em outros relacionamentos? Tente colocar `EAGER` para tudo o que estiver usando na alteração e na remoção.

Comment: ta tudo com EAGER

Comment: e o erro esta nesse relacionamento pois sem ele eu consigo normal

Comment: @paulohddias O código que está na sua pergunta não está todo com *eager*. Além disso, o fato de você tirar esse relacionamento fazer o código funcionar, não significa que o erro está só nele. Como expliquei na resposta, o erro ocorre quando há **mais de um** relacionamento.

Comment: entao o erro do inicio não acontece mais quando mudei para set e coloquei a @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) o problema agora é na sessão estou usando jpa e já tentei criar o opensessionview e não adianta

Comment: estou perdido não sei oque fazer

Comment: Consegui muito obrigado o erro estava na view no jsf, claro depois que eu arrumei o manyTomany como vc disse precisei colocar nao meu f:selectItems o <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.HashSet" /> dai acou o erro de sessão muito obrigado pela ajuda